# SFINAE not working on llvm/clang

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, sfinae

In the following code I'm trying to call a functor with whatever it takes as its parameters, "whatever" being a limited set of options (the two here are not the only ones in my code).

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct call_with_pointer {
    // last resort: T*
    template<class Callable>
    static auto call(Callable &callable, const std::shared_ptr<T> &param) -> decltype(callable(param.get())) {
        return callable(param.get());
    }
};

template<class T>
struct call_with_shared : public call_with_pointer<T> {

    // best: call with shared_ptr<T>.
    // SFINA
    // error: Candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with Callable = Test]: no matching function for call to object of type 'Test'
    template<class Callable>
    static auto call(Callable &callable, const std::shared_ptr<T> &param) -> decltype(callable(param)) {
        return callable(param);
    }

    using call_with_pointer<T>::call;
};


class Test {
public:
    bool operator () (int * x) {
        return *x == 42;
    }
};

int main ()
{
    Test t;

    auto i = std::make_shared<int>(4);

    auto x = call_with_shared<int>::call(t, i); // No matching function for call to 'call'

    return 0;
}
```

This code works just fine in VS and [GCC](http://ideone.com/5pkSf). Unfortunately it does not in clang. The error message is:

> No matching function for call to 'call'
>
> Candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with Callable = Test]: no matching function for
>   call to object of type 'Test'

So it ignores the candidate that uses the smart pointer. Good. But it does not seem to continue with considering the inherited call that would work just fine.

*Question: How can I work around this? How can I make llvm do the right thing here?*

Comment: "How can I make llvm" nitpick: LLVM is not involved here, it's just clang.

Comment: What makes you think clang is wrong here? You are apparently matching on return type, which isn't valid.

Comment: Why does `call_with_pointer::call` still take a `shared_ptr<>` for the second argument..?

Comment: @David No, I'm not matching on anything, I'm counting on SFINAE to eliminate `call_with_shared::call` and use `call_with_pointer::call`.

Comment: @ildjarn Because that's what the caller of `call_with_shared` passes it. It's called `call_with_pointer` not `called_with_pointer` ;)

Comment: It seems that he is writing a dispatcher that takes `shared_ptr` and then forwards the call to the function object. If the function object takes a `shared_ptr` this uses plain forwarding, while if the functor object does not accept `shared_ptr` but only raw pointers, then it will obtain the pointer and forward that. That is, it seems to be an adapter to use functors that don't take `shared_ptr` from code that always uses `shared_ptr` generically

Comment: @Fozi : Ah, thanks for the clarification. Makes much more sense when you put it that way. :-]

Comment: @DavidHammen clang version 3.2 (trunk 156747)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
template<class T>
struct call_with_pointer {
    // last resort: T*
    template<class Callable>
    static auto call(Callable &callable, const std::shared_ptr<T> &param) -> decltype(callable(param.get())) {
        return callable(param.get());
    }
};

template<class T>
struct call_with_pointer_2 {
    // last resort: T*
    template<class Callable>
    static auto call(Callable &callable, const std::shared_ptr<T> &param) -> decltype(callable(param)) {
        return callable(param);
    }
};

template<class T>
struct call_with_shared : public call_with_pointer<T>, public call_with_pointer_2<T>{
    using call_with_pointer<T>::call;
    using call_with_pointer_2<T>::call;
};
```

Comment: While a workaround _is_ what was asked for, I'd be curious to know if Clang is in the wrong by not compiling the original code...

Comment: @ildjarn I think it is... I'll file a bug as soon as I have some time to do it.

Comment: Make sure the bug hasn't already been filed and fixed. Are you working with the most recent release?

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, clang is right because of 7.3.3p15 of C++11(the using declaration of the inherited function template is ignored because it has the same name and parameters as a member function template of the derived class). Although it is pretty clear that that paragraph is defective in not considering these nonconflicting declarations.

You can work it around by using something like `typename YieldFirstType<std::shared_ptr<T>, Callable>::type`  as the second parameter type in one of your templates.

Comment: Sorry, I don't agree. 7.3.3.p15 only states that the member functions override the inherited functions referenced by `using` but it does not state anything about templated member functions that are eliminated later. Eliminated functions should not be considered and thus should not override anything from the base class. The note could be more explicit, however it does not state in any way that it could not work the way GCC an VS is handling it now. Thus, IMHO, GCC and VS are conformant to that point, and, unless you consider eliminated methods part of a class's declaration, clang is not.

Comment: @fozi i do not understand your interpretation of the wording. the spec says "override and/or hide". in this case the base function template is hidden by the derived class function template. name lookup stops as soon as it finda a declaration. anything that could have been found otherwise in outer scopes is said to be "hidden" by the hiding declaration(s). if the overload resolution or template argument deduction fails afterwards, game is over.

Comment: Ok, in this case it would be hidden. Then SFINAE eliminates the derived class function template, and the base class template is in business again. SFINAE is not removing all function templates from all base classes with the same signature, it only removes the one considered at that point.

Comment: @Fozi: Sorry, but no. Once a name is hidden, it's hidden forever. First a set of possible functions is found. Then overload resolution picks from those functions. If overload resolution fails at that point, compilation fails in general -- the compiler does *not* do any further searching to find something at an outer scope than can/will work better.

Comment: @Jerry So what you are saying is that SFINAE **does** remove all function templates with the same signature from all base classes? Does not sound right to me.

Comment: @Fozi it seems to me you don't understand (or have a wrong understanding of) the purpose of your `using` declaration you put into the derived class. Otherwise you would not come up with these comments. Your question serves no purpose if all you come up is saying "no your answer is wrong" if someone answers your question.

Comment: Reading 14.8.3 still leaves me to believe that GCC and VS is right. According to 14.8.3.1 argument detection and checking is performed before any method is added to the candidate list and only then the overload resolution is performed on the candidate list that at that point should not contain the removed method.

Comment: @Johannes I think I understand `using` just fine. Please don't think that just because I have less points I am new to C++.

Comment: @Fozi you have just made me stop help you understand this. Good luck!