# using enable_if to specialize on return type from a base class

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, enable-if

I'm porting a large code base to clang (builds with g++ and intel c++). Code similar to the following snippet compiles and works on [g++ 4.8 - 6.2](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd66fdecb51b9f22)  but fails to compile with [clang 3.8 and 3.9](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/61e21f4b6e7cf856). The second invocation of the MinOp should (AFAICT) get the base class specialization ("Don't call me!"), but clang attempts to instantiate the std::min version and fails:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T> class Vector
{
public:
    Vector() : xyz{} {}
    Vector(T const &x, T const &y, T const &z) : xyz{y, y, z} {}
    Vector<T> min(Vector<T> const &v) { return Vector<T>(std::min(xyz[0], v.xyz[0]), std::min(xyz[1], v.xyz[1]), std::min(xyz[2], v.xyz[2])); }
    T xyz[3];
};

class MinOpBase
{
public:
    template <class T> typename std::enable_if<!std::is_fundamental<T>::value>::type
    operator()(Vector<T> &left, Vector<T> const &right) const { std::cout << "Don't call me!" << std::endl; }
};

class MinOp : public MinOpBase
{
public:
    template <typename T> void operator()(T &left, T const &right) const
    { left = std::min(left, right); }

    // Support component-wise min on vectors of fundamental types
    template <typename T> typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<T>::value>::type
    operator() (Vector<T>  &left, Vector<T>  const &right) const
    {  left.min(right); }

    using MinOpBase::operator();
};

int main()
{
    Vector<double> v1, v2;
    Vector<Vector<double>> vv1, vv2;
    MinOp m;
    m(v1,v2);
    m(vv1,vv2);
}
```

Note that if there is no base class (MinOpBase), and the "Don't call me!" specialization is directly in the MinOp class, [clang works too](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ad2727991875a9d).

Is this use of a using statement to bring in the specialization from the base class valid?

This looks to me like a whole bunch of machinery for not very much value (although of course this has been simplified almost to the point of pointlessness). Better ideas?

Comment: Help me by listing the requirements. There are three conditions that should be considered? two fundamental types, two vectors of fundamental types and two vectors of non-fundamental types?

Comment: Seems to be a bug with clang for me.

Comment: @RichardHodges: Not my code, but the requirements as I understand them are: 1. We have multiple types including fundamentals (float, double) and non-fundamental (complex, Vector, Tensor, etc of floats, doubles, Vector of Vector, etc). 2. We have multiple operations (min, max, assign, sum, etc). Not all operations make sense on all types, but we want this to be handled with run time errors rather than compile or link time. The base class is shared by a number of operations, and lists a number of types that don't support those operations. I could copy those specializations into each derived...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague pointed out that my question is a duplicate of
[SFINAE not working on llvm/clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019781/sfinae-not-working-on-llvm-clang)

I think the conclusion that clang is doing the "right" thing according to the standard is correct. From Johannes Schaub - litb's answer:

> 7.3.3 p15 of C++11 (the using declaration of the inherited function template is ignored because it has the same name and parameters as a
>   member function template of the derived class)

Although the other compilers are doing what probably ought to be the "right" thing. I don't know if this has been reported as a defect in the standard.

Work-arounds include putting all specializations into base classes or modifying one of the argument types of one of the specializations.